# Getting a mean value based on multiple columes value

Tags: r, statistics, mean

I have several variables with a large amount of missing data, I am trying to calculate a mean and standard deviation of Z scores across multiple columns, but only if they have >3 of the variables of interest (it does not matter which of the Z scores as long as there were three). The aim is to be able to say which subjects have a mean Z score one or more SDs away from a reference groups mean Z score. My data is structured like below (but a lot larger)

| Subject | Zscore1 | Zscore2 | Zscore3 | Zscore4 | Zscore5 | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| as4 | -2.4 | -1.2 | NA | -2.3 | 1.6 | ER |
| as1 | -2.6 | -1.4 | -0.7 | -1.4 | -1.4 | TL |
| as8 | -2.7 | NA | -0.1 | NA | -1.1 | TL |
| as10 | NA | -1.7 | -0.9 | 2.3 | 1.7 | ER |

So i would like to code such as:

**IF** there are 3 or more Z scores present **What** is the mean and SD of the Z-scores

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%  
  mutate(not_na_count = rowSums(!is.na(select(., -c(Subject, Group))))) %>% 
  filter(not_na_count >3) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(avg = mean(c_across(2:6), na.rm = TRUE),
         sd = sd(c_across(2:6), na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```

```
 Subject Zscore1 Zscore2 Zscore3 Zscore4 Zscore5 Group not_na_count   avg    sd
  <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 as4        -2.4    -1.2    NA      -2.3     1.6 ER               4 -1.08 1.86 
2 as1        -2.6    -1.4    -0.7    -1.4    -1.4 TL               5 -1.5  0.686
3 as10       NA      -1.7    -0.9     2.3     1.7 ER               4  0.35 1.95
```

Comment: Thanks for this, really helpful. A slight extension you may be able to help with. If I was wanting to have the mean score of Zscore1-Zscore5 together for all the ER group how would I code this? I can get the mean for each the individual columns (Ie te mean for Zscore1, Zscore2 etc seperately) or the mean for each row (subject as4, as1 etc) but cannot get the mean for all the columns and rows of the ER group?

Comment: Do you mean this? `df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(c_across(2:6), na.rm = TRUE),
         sd = sd(c_across(2:6), na.rm = TRUE)
  )` which will give: `Group    avg    sd
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 ER    -0.362 1.92 
2 TL    -1.42  0.878`